# When is a global function not a callable?

Tags: php, function, scope, phpunit

I have a peculiar situation where I need to allow for external definitions of functions, and use them in a test suite. PHP is odd in allowing you to define global functions *anywhere*, but it seems to behave inconsistently.

If I run this as a standalone script, `$a` is `true`:

```php
function php()
{
    return false;
}

$a = is_callable('php');
```

But if I run this same code inside a PHPUnit test (which is testing the injection of externally defined functions), an asssertion for the same thing fails, along these lines:

```php
class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testThis()
    {
        function php()
        {
            return false;
        }

        self::assertTrue(is_callable('php'));
    }
}
```

If it's explicitly in the global scope, it still fails in the same way:

```php
class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testThis()
    {
        self::assertTrue(is_callable('php'));
    }
}

function php()
{
    return false;
}
```

According to [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice versa.

I'm aware that a nested function definition must have been run prior to this in order for it to be accessible, but both of these examples do that.

Does PHPUnit do something to block the definition of global functions?

Comment: Does that latter code happen to be in a `namespace`…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reasonable explanation is that your code is not in global namespace. Like below

```
<?php
namespace App;

function php() {
}

var_dump(is_callable('App\\php'));
```

Comment: Dang, thanks. It is namespaces. I didn't realise they applied to global functions. How can I unalias these functions? `use php` at the top doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: I found how to do that: `namespace { function php() ... }`, but you can't mix that syntax with other unbracketed namespaced code in the same file. I worked around the issue by moving the functions into a separate file.